# Parsing CSV to print line with highest score using bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, csv, awk

I have a CSV like this

```
Parameter Values,Count,% of Results
" david;dd@gmail.com;10300 "," 15 "," 50.0% "
" david;dd@gmail.com;12300 "," 15 "," 50.0% "
" davidk;dk@gmail.com;32300 "," 15 "," 50.0% "
" joe;joe@gmail.com;9200 "," 15 "," 50.0% "
" john;jj@gmail.com;1500 "," 15 "," 50.0% "
```

I want to get the line that has the highest number value, in this case 32300

I already made an attempt at this but it uses several commands

```
export max=$(awk -F, '{split($1,a,";"); print a[3] }' contestEntryTest.csv | tr -d ' "' | sort -nr | head -n 1) ; grep $max contestEntryTest.csv
```

How can i do the above in less commands or one command, how would a more experienced bash programmer do the above problem, just for the learning experience.
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sort, if the file is demo.csv, then

```
sort -t ';' -k3 -n demo.cvs|tail -n 1
```

Comment: wow, that is simple , thanks for the answer. I was just wondering which would have the best performance sort or awk , or is it negligible.

Comment: @tsukimi I think performance base on the size/content of your data, sort will process all entries, but awk process script more complicate, so not easy to say who is faster.

Answer (score 1):

A pure awk way to do the trick :

```
awk -F"[; ]" '($4>v){v=$4}END{print v}' FILE
```

Comment: I changed it a little to `awk -F"[; ]" '(NR>1 && $4>v){v=$4}END{print v}' contestEntryTest.csv` this prints out only the value not the whole line where the value exists